# Merge multiple column values into one column in different table?

Tags: mysql

I've done this before, but I don't remember how. I need to select all rows with unique values from several columns in one table, and insert them into one column in a different table. For the destination table they need to be on separate rows in the destination column.

**Here's an example:**

```
                        Source Table
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  id |  column1   |  column2   |  column3   |  column4   |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1  |   value1   |   value1   |   value1   |   value1   |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  2  |   value2   |   value3   |   value4   |   value5   |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+

 Destination Table
+-----+-----------+
|  id |  column1  |
+-----+-----------+
|  1  |   value1  |
+-----+-----------+
|  2  |   value2  |
+-----+-----------+
|  3  |   value3  |
+-----+-----------+
|  4  |   value4  |
+-----+-----------+
|  5  |   value5  |
+-----+-----------+
```

I tried this query but of course it didn't work because the columns aren't equal.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1)
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3, column4
FROM table1
```

Comment: I decided to just do one column at a time and the query worked, would still like an answer on doing multiple columns though.

Comment: Friend, there's something called PIVOT. I'm learning how to use it yet, but you can try it. I see programmers using this here where i work.

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli MySQL does not have `UNPIVOT` which is what you are thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with union

```
insert into table2(column1)
select column1 from table1
union 
select column2 from table1
union
select column3 from table1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
SELECT col1,
  col2
FROM
  (SELECT rownum X,col_table1 FROM table1
  ) T1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT rownum Y, col_table2 FROM table2
  ) T2
ON T1.X=T2.Y;
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data with output from this query ???

Comment: This probably solves some problem but not the one in this question.

Comment: How does this do the insert ?